# Can Page Layout be deployed in Outbound Changes Set

Tags: deployment, page-layout, change-set

I have created 2 new fields and have arranged it in my **page layout** in **Dev**. I included those page layout in my **outbound changed set**. However when I went in **Sandbox** and uploaded via **inbound changed set** the deployment was successful. But when I went into that particular object, I don't see those fields.

So my question, won't page layout be directly updated in **sandbox** ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes Page Layouts can be included in Change Sets. If you are not seeing your changes in the target environment there are a few things you can check.

1. If there are new fields, you have to include the fields in the Change Set to push the fields onto the object. Page Layouts are only the UI of how a record looks. You have to push the object / field changes also. For example you can create a field an only use it on a report or list view and never on a Page Layout. So make sure to include the Field in your change set.
2. If these are new fields, do the profiles have Field Level Security applied to them? If a Profile does not have FLS visibility to a field, even if the field is on the Page Layout it will not display. You need to include the Profiles in your Change Set so that FLS will be deployed with the new fields in a Change Set.
3. Are Record Types associated with the Page Layouts and Profiles? If you do not include the Profile in your Change Set any setting tightly coupled to the Profile (FLS, Page Layout Assignment) will not push to the target environment.

There could be other things but those are usually the basic ones most folks find.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you went into that particular object do you mean under setup --> Create --> Objects and then your object , If you do not see the feilds there then you  haven't added the custom fields to your change set. If you are talking about the page while creating a new record then I am sure its because the pages have been migrated but have not been assigned to record types under page layout assignment. you need to do that manually. Also ensure you migrate the profile settings or configure it manually in the Sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I just had to include the profiles in the outbound changed set. The fields will not be visible if the Profiles are not added as part of the changed set.